# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the CDATA section

Tags: xml, jsp, tags

Hi I have a JSP file where I load two tag libs:

```
taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"
```

I get an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the CDATA section.
```

The reason is this line:

```
var enabledLoginCharacters = /^[\w \. \- \! \" \§ \$ \% \& \/ \( \) \= \? \* \+ \# \< \> \, \; \: \@]*$/;
```

How can I rewrite this line so it will not cause a XML error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with the SECTION SIGN **§** as it is the only one not in the ASCII subset.

The error is likely caused by the text editor using a different encoding to the one declared by the document.

You can:

- re-encode the document in the declared encoding
- change the encoding declaration to the name of the encoding used to edit it
- replace the literal § with the Unicode expression `\u00A7`